# Question put on hold, after the second edit, will they get notified?

Tags: support, on-hold

I have a question that was put on hold. After reviewing the guidelines, I edited the question. Still, my question was left on hold. Therefore, I expanded and added additional details with a second edit.

For those that put my question on hold. Will they be notified after my second edit to re-open the question? Or has the shipped sailed after my initial edit was "turned down"?

Comment: you first edited it 3 hours ago. It may not have left the re open queue yet. But no, a second edit does not get it back in the queue

Comment: @Patrice https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/20269321

Comment: It looks like after my first edit (3 hours ago), it was still voted "leave closed". I have edited my post since then.

Comment: What I said still stands "a second edit does not get it back in the queue". After the first trip in the queue, it'll only go back if someone votes to reopen it outside of said queue

Comment: So there's a possibility that it won't be opened because of the fact that the second edit won't show up in the queue? I believe my question now has all the necessary details. But if I create a new question, it will be closed as a duplicate. And if I don't do anything at all my question will rot in the dungeons of Stack Overflow. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're in the best spot to get that fixed. Since it's on meta (you could try chatrooms as well), someone with the necessary expertise may review it and cast a reopen vote on it

Answer (score 2):

No one will be notified of any changes to your question, but the question will likely get placed back in the queue for further review.  If it's already in the queue, then it *should* be considering your newest changes.